# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which am running using docker, when i start this application with the docker compose command, it builds the application and also a postgres database, exposing a port `5432` for postgres. This application connects properly with the database without any errors. 
I have another spring boot application which function is to populate a database with data from a google sheet. I get the below error when i try to connect it to the same database as the first application. but the first application connects without any errors.

click here to see error log [role "postgres" does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTG8t.jpg)

Comment: What is the username used by the first application in the connection parameters ? Can you connect to PostgreSQL instance with `psql` and post output of `\du` ?

Comment: the username is also `postgres`

yes i can connect to an instance with the `psql`..

Output of `\du`

                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

Comment: I notice that the exception is occurring during pool initialization. Is the other app going through the pool also? Is the pool setup to accept the postgres user?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but **never** use a superuser for running an application.